# Update mysql version to 5.2 on lamp server using putty

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, lamp, linode

I am trying to configure lamp server using putty,

I followed the instructions and installed **apache**, **mysql** from [Linode](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6). but it shows the installed version of **mysql is 5.1.6** . 
[image]

I need to update the version to **5.2+** , how to upgrade the version so that it does support phpMyAdmin on my server.

Many Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as MySQL 5.2. The major version went straight from 5.1 to 5.5.

Comment: Also, the version number you're looking at (`php-mysql-5.1.6-39`) is for the MySQL PHP extension, not for MySQL itself (which is version `5.0.95-5`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the given link which gives a better upgrade version. You can click the link [here](http://www.ovaistariq.net/490/a-step-by-step-guide-to-upgrading-to-mysql-5-5/) for more information.

Comment: I am very much new to server configuration and these commands. i am using putty for executing my commands. I see # as prefix for the commands, which is different from the tutorial you suggested. they start with '$'

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri it shouldn't be a matter.. try executing the commands it will work.